# How to set lazy loading as the default for Doctrine2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, lazy-loading

I am currently in the process of porting a recent symfony 1.4 application to Symfony2 and Doctrine2. The first thing I noticed once I converted the mapping information (we use YAML files), is that querying for user objects got into an infinite loop.
I played around with the associations and found that I had a cyclical one. I removed that one for debugging purposes, wondering why it would cycle through all those associations at all. I had just asked for all users.

Today I came across the same problem again with another object, only that it stopped after 930 queries and didn't feature an endless loop. It seems that Doctrine2, when it populates the object, queries all objects for each association. No proxying, no lazy loading.

I enabled `fetch: LAZY` on that assocation and voilà, the auto-population stopped!
But now I want to have that as the default behavior, as the model has over 50 associations and I don't want to have to add this line to all of them.

How do I activate lazy loading as the default in Doctrine 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much sweat and reducing the model to a minimal example, I found out why Doctrine fetches all these multiple rows.

The culprit was the ORM tool I am using. When it imported the existing database structure, every relationship was deemed a "one-to-one" relationship. Changing the relationship to "one-to-many" on all 85 associations (as would be correct) <strike>should do</strike> did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

That is actually how lazy loading works. When you try to get a related object, Doctrine will automatically issue another query. Now it is highly discouraged to use lazy loading especially when you're just displaying a list of entities and their related objects. That's the reason you have 960 queries! Still, Doctrine defaults to lazy but you can be aggressive when fetching related entities by joining them in the query which results in a single query.

```
$blogs = $em->createQuery('SELECT b, p FROM Blog b JOIN b.posts p')->getResult();
```

The example above is similar to `SELECT b, p FROM Blog b` but when you'll access posts Doctrine will no longer issue another query.

Comment: Actually that might be part of the problem, but I am not in any way accessing the related objects. In your example I would only be iterating the blogs and echo the title of the blog, not doing **anything** with posts. Doctrine (or Symfony) however populates all posts in each blog with single queries.

I suspect some setting on my part caused the hydration process to fully populate each and every object unnecessarily.

Comment: It seems that circular references in the model have something to do with that. I am currently in the process of compiling a minimal example.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I was able to find the bug in the model, several relationships were incorrectly imported as "one-to-one" instead of "one-to-many" by my modelling tool.